# backward slash followed by a number in python strings

Tags: python, windows, string, directory, slash

I've encountered a problem in Python when dealing with backward slashes followed by numbers  inside a string. I use windows OS environment.

This becomes especially annoying when you have numbers in the beginning of a name in a directory.

Ex: `"P:\70_parseFile\80_FileDir\60_FA_050"`

This was a discovery for me that you can create special characters if you do "\1", "\2", "\3"... and so on. As wonderful as this seems, I have to ask on how to go about turning this off, or what other different string function is there that doesn't have this special feature?

Thanks, all!

Comment: Is this just a problem when using regexes?

Comment: You can use forward slash in folder/file names.

Comment: I did not use this for regexes and neither could I replace the backward slashes to forward slashes as the special ("\8...") function gets called first before any string variable manipulation. What happened was that I appended file names using os.path.join() which resulted in what you see in the example above. It was a simple misfortune of not appending files as raw string. Thanks icecrime!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Backslash those backslashes:

  ```
  "P:\\70_parseFile\\80_FileDir\\60_FA_050"
  ```
- Use a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), in which the backslash loses its "special meaning"

  ```
  r"P:\70_parseFile\80_FileDir\60_FA_050"
  ```

Comment: Thank you!
Using raw string also automatically converted converted my directory string variable from single slash "\" to double slash "\\".